# How can I add multilines in firebase cloud firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I started making a web project something looks like whatsapp and I am using firebase as my db.
My problem is I can't type a multiline chat to the db
I've tried changing the `<input type="text">` to `<textarea type="text">` but when I click on submit it changes to a single line.. for better understanding please check the the pictures by clicking on the hyperlinks

When Typed 
[image: When Typed]

When I hit submit button 
[image: When I hit submit button]

I hope my problem will be solved soon

Thanks

Comment: The Firestore database itself does nothing to strings that you store in it. If the string contains a newline when it's stored, it'll contain the same newline when you read it. If that is not working for you, the problem is coming from the application code somewhere. So please edit your question to include the [minimum code with which any of use can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Adding your code to the question is always a good place to start. I suspect it is how you are handling multi-line text in node.js. Update your question and take a look at this GitHub repository on how to handle [multi-line text](https://github.com/rjrodger/mstring).